# After hosting the website on firebase I am not able to view content

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have followed the firebase guidelines to host the website on firebase hosting, but the content of the website is not visible . I am seeing this on my screen as shared in the picture[image]

what should i do about? please guide

Comment: You should try visiting it from any other device. Is it possible for you to share URL to that?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I tried from another device as will same thing happening

Comment: Did you check if there are files in your project's `public` folder ?

Comment: @Ashish yes, there are no files , how to ensure the files are always there automatically?

Comment: It depends if your using any framework or plain html css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have setup your website in the correct folder as Firebase uses folders to contain data for specific services, `public` for hosting and `functions` for cloud functions. You can find out what folder this is by opening the firebase.json`file at the root of your project You should find something similar if you used`firebase init` correctly

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
```

Once you run the command `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only hosting` everything inside this folder is uploaded to your hosting website.
Make sure you also check both URLs provided by Firebase as the `web.app` URL tends to take longer to update and deploy.

- `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com`

Beyond these fundamental tips I would also make sure that your entry point into the website is also correct, opening the hosting folder (public or otherwise) - and opening up the index.html within should yield you the same site found on `*.firebaseapp.com`