# Firebase Hosted Site not displaying intended content

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I just deployed a React app with a firebase backend to Firebase Hosting using
`firebase init, firebase serve and firebase deploy.`

The link is available here: https://the-circumspect.web.app/

However, only the web application icon is showing. What am I doing wrong and how can I set it up to show my site content?

Comment: please check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508164/after-hosting-the-website-on-firebase-i-am-not-able-to-view-content), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274084/firebase-hosting-not-showing-up-app) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049855/my-website-is-not-showing-after-deploy-in-firebase-how-to-solve-this)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your directory structure and `firebase.json`?

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj, here is a link to the image showing the directory structure - https://i.imgur.com/QVHjAZF.png